# Are there books or training exercises that scribes use to strengthen their skills?

Tags: safrus, writing-printing, art, torah-writing

I'm not a scribe and I have no plans on becoming a scribe. This would not be used for religious practice or religious needs. I just happen to enjoy the practice of Hebrew calligraphy and I'm interested in strengthening my abilities around that.

I was just curious if there were books or materials scribes in training use to strengthen their abilities and practice the art. Do materials such as these exist? Both books and online materials are welcome.

Comment: Try כתיבת סתם by R' Mordechai Mendolovitz (I've never actually read it)

Answer (score 1):

You can get ready made training sets which often include instruction manuals - for example [here](https://www.judaicaplace.com/safrus-set-english/696177623465/)

You might also want to explore a sofrus supplies shop which often have a great deal of books and supplies to get started or even like yourself, for those who have a vague interest. For example [Mercaz HaSofrim](https://merkazhasofrim.com/sofrus/seforim-books-cds.html) which also has a cool 'ask the sofer' portal.

There are several seforim available on the subject matter several that you can see in the Mercaz HaSofrim link